# SQL Select syntax workaround

Tags: sql, select

Let's say I have two existing tables, "dogs" and "cats":

```
 dog_name | owner
 ---------+------
 Sparky   | Bob
 Rover    | Bob
 Snoopy   | Chuck
 Odie     | Jon

 cat_name | owner
 ---------+------
 Garfield | Jon
 Muffy    | Sam
 Stupid   | Bob
```

How do I write a query with this output?

```
 owner | num_dogs | num_cats
 ------+----------+---------
 Bob   |     2    |    1
 Chuck |     1    |    0
 Sam   |     0    |    1
 Jon   |     1    |    1
```

**The answer I've got is the next query**

```
select owner, sum(num_dogs), sum(num_cats) from
  (select owner, 1 as num_dogs, 0 as num_cats from dogs
   union
   select owner, 0 as num_dogs, 1 as num_cats from cats)
group by owner
```

**but the problem is that sql doesn't support "select * from (select...)" 
type of query**

Instead, there has to be a table name after "from".

Unfortunately I can't afford myself to have temporary table or a table 
created with "select into" clause. I need some workaround for the 
proposed solution where a nested select clause is formed in this way.

What's your opinion?

Cheers

Comment: What kind of database engine is this?

Comment: it seems to me your "dogs" and "cats" tables are begging to be combined into a "pets" table with the columns (name, owner, type).  then you'd do select owner, type, count(name) from pets group by owner, type.  I think.  Didn't test the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My SQL does, just need to name the table...  What database are you using?

```
 select owner, sum(num_dogs), sum(num_cats) from
  (select owner, 1 as num_dogs, 0 as num_cats from dogs
   union all
   select owner, 0 as num_dogs, 1 as num_cats from cats) as g
 group by owner
```

Comment: Sorry. I was sure I tried it.
It works fine with naming after parenthesis.
thanks.

Comment: This query is incorrect.  As is it assumes the the whole list of owners is in both tables.  Even if you change it to LEFT OUTER JOIN, you are assuming the list of owners is wholly in the primary table.  To get the accurate list you need to use the UNION ALL approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table cats (cat_name varchar(8), owner varchar(8))
create table dogs (dog_name varchar(8), owner varchar(8))
create table owners (owner varchar(8))

insert into owners values ('Jon')
insert into owners values ('Bob')
insert into owners values ('Chuck')
insert into owners values ('Sam')

insert into dogs values ('Sparky', 'Bob')
insert into dogs values ('Rover', 'Bob')
insert into dogs values ('Snoopy', 'Chuck')
insert into dogs values ('Odie', 'Jon')

insert into cats values ('Garfield', 'Jon')
insert into cats values ('Muffy', 'Sam')
insert into cats values ('Stupid', 'Bob')

select 
    owners.owner,
    count(distinct dog_name) as num_dogs,
    count(distinct cat_name) as num_cats
from 
    owners
        left outer join dogs on dogs.owner = owners.owner
        left outer join cats on cats.owner = owners.owner
group by owners.owner
```

Note that count(dog_name) should probably be count(dog_id)... multiple dogs can have same name different owners (heck... same name same owner is probably allowed).

Note the addition of DISTINCT to the count(..) to correct problem.

Comment: Uhm... yes it does:
    owner  num_dogs  num_cats
    Bob    2         1
    Chuck  1         0
    Jon    1         1
    Sam    0         1

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd say you need to add UNION **ALL** io just UNION to make this query work.
2. You need to name your inner select.

   SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table) **MyInnerSelect**

A better solution would be to create a table Owner and join the dog & cat tables.

Answer (score 1):

"but the problem is that sql doesn't support "select * from (select...)" type of query"

Sure it does.  you just need to give it a name like "select * from (select...)a"

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the subquery.

```
select owner, sum(num_dogs), sum(num_cats)
from (
    select owner, 1 as num_dogs, 0 as num_cats from dogs
    union all
    select owner, 0 as num_dogs, 1 as num_cats from cats
) a
group by owner
```

Notice the `a` immediately following the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method, just for fun.

```
select o.owner, nd.numdogs, nc.numcats
from owners o
left join (select owner, count(dog_name) as numdogs
           from dogs
           group by owner) nd on nd.owner=o.owner
left join (select owner, count(cat_name) as numcats
           from cats
           group by owner) nc on nc.owner=o.owner
```

Comment: SQL execution plan comes out faster than currently accepted answer, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the subquery:

```
select sq.owner, sum(sq.num_dogs), sum(sq.num_cats) from
    (select owner, 1 as num_dogs, 0 as num_cats from dogs
     union
     select owner, 0 as num_dogs, 1 as num_cats from cats
    ) as sq
group by sq.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
coalesce (d.owner, c.owner),
count(distinct d.dog_name) as num_dogs,
count(distinct c.cat_name) as num_cats
from dogs d
full join cats c on d.owner = c.owner
group by coalesce (d.owner, c.owner)
```

only because I don't like unions and sub selects for some reason... :)

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this, more for highlighting different ways than necessarily performance.

In SQL Server -

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(c.owner, d.owner) AS owner, 
COUNT(d.dog_name) num_dogs, 
COUNT(c.cat_name) num_cats
FROM
dogs d
FULL OUTER JOIN 
cats c
ON 
d.owner = c.owner
GROUP BY
c.owner, d.owner
ORDER BY
ISNULL(c.owner, d.owner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create an owners table with all of the owner names?  If so, the following query will give you the output you're after:

```
SELECT
     owners.owner,
     count(distinct dog_name),
     count(distinct cat_name)
FROM
     (
     Owners
     LEFT JOIN cats ON
          owners.owner = cats.owner
     )
LEFT JOIN dogs ON
     Owners.owner = dogs.owner
GROUP BY
     Owners.owner;
```